# Mirror Maker is failing with ConnectRestException

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

We are using Apache Kafka Mirror Maker 2.0 to replicate the data/records from One DC to another DC. We have Mirror Maker cluster of 3 nodes. We don't have much load in terms of messages per seconds, only 2 topics are being replicated from one DC to another DC.

Whenever we start the Mirror Maker process, it starts gracefully for some duration (not fixed though), we see messages getting replicated. After sometime, it will start throwing ConnectRestException.

We start seeing the following exception in loop and replication gets stopped ultimately.

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectRestException: Error trying to forward REST request: Invalid URI host: null (authority: null)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient.httpRequest(RestClient.java:147)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.lambda$reconfigureConnector$27(DistributedHerder.java:1473)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI host: null (authority: null)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient.checkHost(HttpClient.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient.newHttpRequest(HttpClient.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient.newRequest(HttpClient.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient.newRequest(HttpClient.java:453)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient.httpRequest(RestClient.java:107)
    ... 6 more
[2024-01-30 10:03:08,871] ERROR [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=kaas-prodoccrt-mm2] Request to leader to reconfigure connector tasks failed (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1476)
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectRestException: Error trying to forward REST request: Invalid URI host: null (authority: null)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient.httpRequest(RestClient.java:147)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.lambda$reconfigureConnector$27(DistributedHerder.java:1473)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI host: null (authority: null)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient.checkHost(HttpClient.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient.newHttpRequest(HttpClient.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient.newRequest(HttpClient.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient.newRequest(HttpClient.java:453)
    at org.apache.kafk
```

On restart, it works fine for sometime and it again it repeats. Is there any Mirror Maker configuration we are missing as it saying Invalid URL host: null.